# NTF mint successful but can't sell any of minted tokens. OpenSea error 404

Tags: nft, opensea, mint

I've successfully deployed the smart contract, then minted the NTFs through the script. Now I want to list them for auction or for sell but OpenSea API returns 404 error not found.
I've tried to get the asset of NTF through OpenSea API and it returns the asset.

Here is my code for selling the NFT:

[image]

The OpenSea error response:

[image]

Comment: Not that is means much but same happens to me using the interface of opensea. Maybe they have a bug on the testnet I would hope.

Comment: So actually it was caused by the bug on OpenSea API and their interface also.

Comment: @BenjaminBerta: Could you please share, when deployed to mainnet, did it work? I am seeing the same error on rinkeby testnet.

Comment: Deploy was on August 6, and about that time OpenSea API had some issues and it was also on rinekby testnet.